# Can I make a subdirectory in public:// viewable in Media module's UI?

Tags: 7, files, media

In Drupal 7 Media module (admin/content/media) is it possible to view subdirectories in my public:// domain? I have images and files from legacy site that were uploaded in a variety of subdirectories, i.e.

sites/default/files/presentations

sites/default/files/sponsors

etc.

My Media module browser lists all the files that exist in the main public:// directory, but doesn't show any of the subdirectories, even though I confirmed via FTP the subdirectories exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can five a try to [filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) module if it helps you. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ...  full featured Document Management module that has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated file management module supporting role and user based security. Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect documents for safe access and distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to change the Media module's file selection process so my users still cannot see the public:// subdirectories when they look for files, and I can't grant them file handling permissions or all hell will break loose

Comment: Well, that seems to be the only course of action. Thanks @arpitr for the module suggest.

Comment: @longboardnode did it work for you?